# How to access encoder in scoring script in azure ml studio

Tags: azure, azure-machine-learning-service

I have been using azure ml studio notebook to train and register a regression model. I have used one hot encoder to encode categorical variable and saved it as a pickle file in azure ml studio. I have registered my model eg. prediction.pkl model in azure. I was in the process of creating an online endpoint for the model. While developing the scoring script it struck me how will  be using the one hot encoder so I can perform .transform on the categorical column when the model is put to use post deployment.

P.s. New to azure

I haven’t tried anything yet as I am not able to find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

As you already saved your One Hot Encoder as a pickle file in Azure ML Studio, you should also register your One Hot Encoder in Azure ML Studio, just like you registered your model.  This will allow you to reference it in your scoring script.

Once your both models are registered, you will need to load both the model and the One Hot Encoder in your scoring script.

Below is sample code for reference:

```py
import os
import pickle
from azureml.core.model import Model

def init():
    global one_hot_encoder, model
    
    # Load the One Hot Encoder
    encoder_path = Model.get_model_path('one_hot_encoder_name')
    with open(encoder_path, 'rb') as file:
        one_hot_encoder = pickle.load(file)
    
    # Load the model
    model_path = Model.get_model_path('model_name')
    with open(model_path, 'rb') as file:
        model = pickle.load(file)

def run(raw_data):
    # Use the encoder to transform the data
    data = ... # Your code to extract data from raw_data
    transformed_data = one_hot_encoder.transform(data)
    
    # Make prediction
    result = model.predict(transformed_data)
    return result.tolist()
```

For more details you can check [multi-model-register-and-deploy](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/deployment/deploy-multi-model/multi-model-register-and-deploy.ipynb) notebook.